# Wrap Words in Square Bracket Instead of sglQuotedString or dblQuotedString

Tags: javascript, python, escaping, pyparsing

I'm using pyparsing to parse a boolean string query. So I will be sending a string that looks something like this:

```
string = "'foo' AND 'bar' OR NOT 'foobar'"
```

I'm using `sqlQuotedString()` but there will be times that the string being parsed will contain other types of punctuation like apostrophes so it could be like this:

```
string = "'foo' AND 'ba'r' OR NOT 'fo0-bar'"
```

I tried setting up `QuotedString("'", escChar = '\\')` but I'm sending the string from javascript and I can't seem to find a way to include the backslash in my string. I've tried this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    if(v[i] === '"') {
        v[i] = [v.slice(0, i), "\\", v.slice(v)].join('');
    }
}
```

and I've tried adding extra backslashes (`"\\\\\\\"`) but the string still shows without the `"\"` in it.

Is there a way to just set up pyparsing so that it expects a word wrapped in square brackets rather than single or double quotes i.e. `[word]` vs. `'word'` or `"word"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pyparsing's `QuotedString` class, specifying '[' as the opening character, and ']' as the ending character:

```
>>> from pyparsing import OneOrMore,QuotedString
>>> bracketed = QuotedString('[',endQuoteChar=']')
>>> OneOrMore(bracketed).parseString('[sldflsdjkf][asdf][sdf]').asList()
['sldflsdjkf', 'asdf', 'sdf']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. I tried QuotedString but did not have the endQuoteChar typed in correctly *sigh*.